# WP submenu doesn't make drop down

Tags: wordpress

in my website http://www.nivic.co.il/ there is a menu (at the right side) with submenus, but when I make hover on menu item submenu doesn't appear, but in the code it actually there. Advice me something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can tell, you have JavaScript that does this:

1. Hover over menu item
2. Change submenu 'ul' element from "display: none; visibility: hidden;" to "display: block; visibility: visible;"

However, your CSS also has this rule:

```
.sf-menu ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: -999em;
}
```

All your submenus are positioned off screen following this rule, and hovering over your top menu items, doesn't change this rule.

If you want your submenus to appear, you need to change the position and top properties when hovering over your top menu items. You should be able to add these properties to your existing rule:

```
.sf-menu li:hover ul, .sf-menu li.sfHover ul {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  /* your existing properties */
}
```